# NodeJS/Express Workflow with CoffeeScript & Stylus

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, express, stylus

I have decided to use ExpressJS with CoffeeScript and Stylus. Usually when I work with CoffeeScript, I do a `coffee --watch` and something similar for Compass/SASS. Here, since CoffeeScript and Stylus are available as a NPM package, I was thinking if its possible to write CoffeeScript and Stylus and have Node/Express compile them when required? This way I wont need a watcher anymore.

Also when I create an express app using `express -c stylus`, in `app.js` I get additional:

```
app.use(require('stylus').middleware({ src: __dirname + '/public' }));
```

What does it actually do? It doesn't appear to compile my CSS? When I put

```
body
    background: red
```

into the default style.styl file, restart server, it doesn't appear to show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so theres **[connect-assets](https://github.com/TrevorBurnham/connect-assets)** for this exact purpose. Now I am still looking for something for server side ...

Answer (score 0):

try to set

```
var stylus = require('stylus');

app.use(stylus.middleware({
 src: __dirname + '/public',
 compile: function(str, path) {
  return stylus(str)
    .set('filename', path)
    .set('compress', false)
    .set('warn', true);
 }
}));
```

This compile function is not required, but without it the `styl` files don't get compiled..